# Logi Analytics: write rows in a table in XML

Tags: xml, datatable, analytics

How do I write a table in the Logi XML?
I start with:

```
<PanelContent Height="1000">
          <DataTable ID="tblPreview" Width="1000" ResizableColumns="True">
            <DataTableColumn ID="colLabel" Header="Label" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colAccepted" Header="Accepted" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colEnriched" Header="Enriched" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colValidated" Header="Validated" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colToBeSigned" Header="To be signed" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colToRelease" Header="To release" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colReleased" Header="Released" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colSending" Header="Sending" />
            <DataTableColumn ID="colSent" Header="Sent" />
</DataTable>
```

How do I add rows to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lumpi,

For dynamic rows (where a row is displayed for each row in your datasource), add Label elements under each DataTableColumn element, like so:

```
<DataTable ID="tblPreview" Width="1000" ResizableColumns="True">
  <DataTableColumn ID="colLabel" Header="Label">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column1~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colAccepted" Header="Accepted">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column2~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colEnriched" Header="Enriched">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column3~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colValidated" Header="Validated">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column4~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colToBeSigned" Header="To be signed">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column5~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colToRelease" Header="To release">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column6~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colReleased" Header="Released">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column7~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colSending" Header="Sending">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column8~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colSent" Header="Sent">
    <Label Caption="@Data.Column9~" />
  </DataTableColumn>
</DataTable>
```

The data references will tie back to columns in your datasource.

For static rows, use the Rows element:

```
<Rows>
  <Row ID="row1">
    <Column ID="colLabel">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value1~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colAccepted">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value2~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colEnriched">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value3~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colValidated">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value4~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colToBeSigned">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value5~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colToRelease">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value6~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colReleased">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value7~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colSending">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value8~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colSent">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value9~" />
    </Column>
  </Row>
  <Row ID="row2">
    <Column ID="colLabel">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value10~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colAccepted">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value11~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colEnriched">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value12~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colValidated">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value13~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colToBeSigned">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value14~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colToRelease">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value15~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colReleased">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value16~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colSending">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value17~" />
    </Column>
    <Column ID="colSent">
      <Label Caption="@Data.value18~" />
    </Column>
  </Row>
</Rows>
```

Hope this helps.